VS Code Proxy Kerberos Auth not authenticating
I am trying to setup Kerberos auth for proxy on VS Code for my company; however, it seems like it's presenting me with authentication issues with error 407 from the logs Output->Window (cant paste output as it contains some company details).
Currently Running:
VS Code 1.85.2
Windows 11
Expecting VS Code to start picking up proxy and the Logs in Output->Window should show everything being authenticated normally and extensions using the proxy like how it should work in basic auth.
I have tried basic authentication with the following settings.json file and it works fine. (variables used within {})
{
    "http.proxy": "http://{username}:{password}@{proxy_url}:{proxy_port}",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
    "http.proxySupport": "fallback",
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
}


I have tried setting it with just the proxy url and hoping it would using kerberos auth but no luck
{
    "http.proxy": "http://{proxy_url}:{proxy_port}",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
    "http.proxySupport": "fallback",
}

I have tried a combination of options in proxyStrictSSL as well as proxySupport. Also tried setting proxyKerberosServicePrincipal manually but no luck.
All of them lead to Error 407 , from the Output->Window (cant paste output as it contains some company details)
The only thing I haven't tried is changing proxyAuthorization, but I have no clue how to do it for other auth from apart from Basic, and I can't find it on any docs online. I have also tried to set it at the system level but no luck there. I can't find any documentation online on how to set it up either, but looking at the release notes and settings, it looks like it is supported.
